# Get tweets in cocos2d

Tags: ios, twitter, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to integrate tweets from a twitter account as the headlines for a scrolling news bar in a cocos2D iPhone app. So my question is how do I go about retrieving the tweets from the wanted account. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the twitter framework which is available in ios or use the ShareKit library

If you want this twitter integration to work fr ios 4.0 users n less, u also need to use MGTwitterEngine

Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios